# Can a publicly known gap trading strategy be profitable and if so why?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies

Newbie to this field, please forgive any lacking knowledge...

There is various literature [(example)](https://www.leadingtrader.com/public/trading-the-opening-gap-strategy/) on trading according to strategies which assume that (in the absence of a large gap, or major news) the Dow will return to something approximating yesterday's closing price shortly after the market opens.

Can such a strategy, if publicly known, deliver consistent above market returns for the risk (e.g. as defined by sharpe ratio)? Intuitively I would think that any correlation so obvious/public would be reflected in the price already. If this is not the case then how does it remain so?

Comment: You must do your own analysis. (The video you linked uses Nasdaq Index, which has problems with how it is calculated (stale data), you must use a *tradeable instrument* such as Nasdaq futures, you must take into account transaction costs, etc.). Do it *right*. My impression is this kind of strategy worked well during Financial Crisis of 2008-2011, with those big moves overnight, it is not working well know. Nothing is forever. Do your own analysis when you read this kind of article.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not doing it at all, though I know someone who is. They haven't been using it long but are happy with the returns so far. Are you suggesting that if I were to do my own analysis I would reveal these returns are balanced by a large hidden risk of some sort (stop orders notwithstanding)? Logically I think either that must be the case, or that my understanding of what happens to well known correlations in the market is wrong.

Comment: Hidden risks is one possibility (the "peso problem" that economists talk about), another is a period of positive performance followed by a period of negative performance (either because the strategy becomes too well known or simply the market environment changes). Your skepticism is warranted, but keep an open mind (and keep in touch with your friend) ... sometimes stupid ideas do work ;)